# Open a popup and close it automatically after few seconds using Javascript setTimeout/setInterval

Tags: jquery, clearinterval, magento2.2

I have created a ajax call function after addtocart success.

I need to open custom popup every 4 sec after addtocart and closed it after 4 sec.

But also I need to clear interval after closing popup.

In custom function ajax success contains,

```
var id = setTimeout(timer, 5000);
 function timer() {
   alert(1);
   $("#qty-popup").show();
    setInterval(function () {
       $("#qty-popup").hide();
    }, 5000);
  clearInterval(id);
   }
```

But its not working. How to do this (clear interval)?

Comment: do you need your popup to open and wait for 4 seconds then close automatically. then open again after 4 seconds? you have written `every 4 seconds` in your question, so i am thinking??

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some `onClose` event for the popup:

```
var id = setTimeout(timer, 5000);
function timer() {
    $("#qty-popup").toggle();       
}
```

For the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'url'
  data: data,
  success: function(){ 
    clearInterval(id);
  },
  error: function(){
    clearInterval(id);
  }
});
```

Comment: How to do this in ajax success

Comment: Also i hide the popup after 5 sec

Comment: I don't understand, In what cases you want to show/hide, you wrote different on your question, please update it. For Ajax you have the events `success` and `error`. you should clear the interval there!

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Updated, this should cover all your needs, using a toggle, if you don't know a toggle, basicly you need to have 1 interval, and to keep the state of you popup, then if 4 seconds passed and its close so open it, after 4 more seconds close it

Comment: Its a auto close popup(after 5 sec).Not use $("#popup-close-btn).

Comment: You dont hve to have a blose btn, notice the `toggle` function